# dojo 1.7 dojox/form/Uploader not displaying the file picker dialog

Tags: javascript, dojo

My end game is to add the uploader to a dialog. That was not working so I went the simple route to see if it would work. Below is as about as simple as I can go and sadly the file picker does not display when the button is clicked. I am working in Firefox and Chrome. If anyone would be kind enough to look this over and find a goof I would appreciate it.

```js
require(["dojox/form/Uploader",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojox/form/uploader/plugins/IFrame",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],
  function(Uploader, dom) {
    var u = new Uploader({
      name: "myPhoto",
      label: "Upload Your Photo",
      multiple: false,
      uploadOnSelect: true,
      url: "to/the/ethreal"
    });
    dom.byId("myDiv").appendChild(u.domNode);
  });
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
  <!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note; you will not gain iframe / html5 support, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343652/programmatic-dojox-uploader-ajax-upload-not-working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I thought it would end up being something stupid, but **Widgets need to be started.** After half a day thrown away on that one, I wish the dojo examples would not leave out such key aspects.

The operation function looks like:

```js
require(["dojox/form/Uploader",
    "dojo/dom",
    "dojox/form/uploader/plugins/IFrame",
    "dojo/domReady!"
  ],
  function(Uploader, dom) {
    var u = new Uploader({
      name: "myPhoto",
      label: "Upload Your Photo",
      multiple: false,
      uploadOnSelect: true,
      url: "to/the/ethreal"
    }, "myDiv");
    u.startup();
  });
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="screen">
  <!-- load dojo and provide config via data attribute -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.1/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
</head>

<body class="claro">
  <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
```

As I am sure has been stated many times, the best place for info is the tests at [Nightly Build](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/). I Found the missing nugget on [FileUpload](http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dojox/form/tests/test_FileInput.html).

Comment: Thanks, that helped me. Basically you needed to add the "u.startup" after declaring the object! Very trivial and perhaps, not very intuitive, but it makes all the difference when you're wondering why the control is not displaying the file explorer.